# Solr error extending ValueSourceParser

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm trying to write a custom FunctionQuery for Solr 3.6.2 and am running into problems when trying to start Solr. The error that I get is:

`SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating ValueSourceParser, CustomScoreParser is not a org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser`

However, from what I can see everything is in order:

```
public class CustomScoreParser extends ValueSourceParser{
    @Override
    public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fqp) throws ParseException {
        return new MyValueSource();
    }
}
```

I have registered the CustomScoreParser in solrconfix.xml and implemented MyValueSource; however, I'm still getting this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your solrconfig.xml ? is it MyValueSource or CustomScoreParser  ???

Comment: The relevant line is:

    <valueSourceParser name="customr" class="CustomScoreParser" />

Comment: does it not have any package name ??

Comment: No, but I did test what would happen if I added it to a package and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this. I solved this problem by downloading the Solr source and compiling it on my own machine. Everything worked as expected then.